# R draw multiple models in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have done multiple survival models using kaplan-Meir approach, each survival model was built by extracting sub set of data to different R Data table based on group column showed in the data table. I can plot each survival curve separate but I want to plot all these different models in one plot. what is the best way to do that.

```
 userid        lifespan_days              event        group
2                    4657                    1           A
4                    4658                    1           A
16                   1106                    1           A
50                    458                    1           A
51                   4393                    1           A
57                    305                    1           A
```

It would be great to do this in ggplot, By search I found following [`ggplot2` - plot multiple models on the same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294445/ggplot2-plot-multiple-models-on-the-same-plot) but I have problem of doing such scenario due to the nature of my data. For example `userid` is from multiple websites so `userid=2` can exist under another group.

Lets say using above data.table I have created following:

```
a_time <- dt$lifespan_days
a_event <- dt$event
survival_model_a <- survfit(Surv(a_time, a_event) ~ 1)
plot(survival_model_a)
```

this will only plot one similary in the same plot I want to plot the model that I built for group b data which is in a different `data.table / data.frame`

Comment: I'm note sure what exactly you're plotting, maybe you can include some code. If you don't use ggplot you can just call `lines()` instead of `plot()` for the subsequent plots.

Comment: @amoebe I added a example just to make it clear.

Comment: If you provide your full dataset, or at least a much large sample that includes multiple groups, I'll show you a ggplot solution (unless someone else does first...). Upload your data somewhere and post a link in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `lines()` for subsequent plot calls like this:

```
b_time <- dtB$lifespan_days
b_event <- dtB$event
survival_model_b <- survfit(Surv(b_time, b_event) ~ 1)
lines(survival_model_b)
```

If you want to use ggplot2, there's two good answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph).

Comment: This is actually works, what would be the best way to convert this to ggplot?

Comment: I added a link to some ggplot answers with many upvotes, unfortunately I don't really know ggplot.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot all models in one without subsetting using:

```
dt <- read.table(header=T, text="userid        lifespan_days              event        group
2                    4657                    1           A
4                    4658                    0           A
16                   1106                    1           B
50                    458                    1           B
51                   4393                    1           C
57                    305                    1           A")

library(survival)
a_time <- dt$lifespan_days
a_event <- dt$event
survival_model_a <- survfit(Surv(a_time, a_event) ~ dt$group)
plot(survival_model_a, col = rainbow(length(unique(dt$group))))
```